# Adding multiple widgets depending on a R object

Tags: r, shiny

I a newbie in shiny and I want to add `input$n` widgets to my webpage, where `input$n` is a numeric given by another widget in my page?

Is it possible? And how?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using Shiny Modules. In the following example, the application dynamically creates N `textInput` from a `numericInput`.

```
library(shiny)

# Module UI containing a widget
widgetUI <- function(id, i) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    textInput(inputId = ns("text"), label = paste("widget", i))
  )
}

# Module server, unused here, just prints the widgets value in console
widgetServer <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$text,{
    print(input$text)
  })
}

# Main UI page
ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput(inputId = "n", label = "Number of widgets", value = 2),
  uiOutput("widgets")
)

# Main server
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$widgets <- renderUI({
    req(input$n)
    # call the module UI n times
    tagList(
      lapply(1:input$n, function(i) {
          widgetUI(id = paste0("widget", i), i)
      })
    )
  })
  
  observe({
    # call the module server n times
    lapply(1:input$n, function(i) {
      callModule(widgetServer, id = paste0("widget", i))
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```